# Why when through VPN the sokcet get a RST packet

Tags: sockets

My program have a server and a client, they are communicate with socket.No problem when i test them in intranet environment. And no problem test them in Internet enviroment.I use NAT for setting a globalization server. But when the client through VPN(TinyVPN) connect with the server, and do anything four minutes later client and server receive a RST packet almost at the same time.
Why the client connect with the server through VPN, because the sever and client all in my company, can not access as the internet environment, so I use VPN make the internet access at my company.
I am puzzles, when I use wireshark capture the last packet at server and client, they all receive a RST packet almost at the same time.
I am also google search RST, have a lot of opinions for this question. I do not close operation, and do any communication operation. Only connect and wait, 4 minutes later receive a RST packet, i do not the reason. Please help you.
I copied parts of my source code as follow.

```
    private void OnReadComplete( IAsyncResult ar ) 
{
        ClientUser currentUser;
        int CbRead = -1;

        try
        {
             lock (this.syncSocket)
            {
                //set current opration usser
                currentUser = (ClientUser)ar.AsyncState;
                //Notice::::::::::::::There have a error
                CbRead = currentUser.Stream.EndRead(ar);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException IOExcep)
        {   
            if (m_ClientUser.IsConnected)
            {
                DisconnectClient();
                LogOutput.Logger.Error("IOExcep, Error: " + IOExcep.Message);
            }
    }    

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason is that your VPN times out having no traffic flowing through it and disconnects, thus shutting down all the established TCP connections through it.

Comment: But i do not set timeout at VPN sever.